# Pandas to_sql multiple inserts

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

I am creating a Pyhton-script to read measure values from data and write them to a PostgreSQL database.
My problem is that pandas to_sql and psycopg2s copy_from create eight entries for each value and I don't know where the problem is.
First I read all data from a file

```
all = pd.read_csv(file, encoding = "latin-1", index_col = False, usecols = [4, 5, 10, 58, 59, 61], names = ['error', 'messstelle', 'counter', 'room', 'rad', 'time'], header = 0, delimiter = '\t')
```

Then I must seperate the different values and add a datatype

```
counter = all[['messstelle', 'counter', 'time']]
counter['datentyp'] = 2
counter = counter.rename(columns={'counter' : 'wert'})
```

Finally I write all values in the df to the database

```
counter.to_sql('wert', engine, if_exists = 'append')
```

And here my problems begin. Everything works fine, but when i open pgadmin every value is inserted eight times.

Does someone know what I did wrong? I am sitting here for several hours now, trying to fix the problem. But until now without success.

I hope someone might help me! Thanks

Update:
Input:

```
    messstelle   wert              time  datentyp
0     13343366   7704  09.04.2014 07:01         2
1     13343367  12406  09.04.2014 07:01         2
2     13343369   6135  09.04.2014 07:01         2
3     13343371   2156  09.04.2014 07:02         2
4     13343372   6629  09.04.2014 07:02         2
5     13343373   5799  09.04.2014 07:02         2
6     13343375   5473  09.04.2014 07:02         2
7     13343376   6962  09.04.2014 07:02         2
8     13343377   9174  09.04.2014 07:02         2
```

Output:

```
             wert  datentyp                time
messstelle
13338865    56604         2 2014-04-09 07:06:00
13338865    56604         2 2014-04-09 07:06:00
13338865    56604         2 2014-04-09 07:06:00
13338865    56604         2 2014-04-09 07:06:00
13338865    56604         2 2014-04-09 07:06:00
13338865    56604         2 2014-04-09 07:06:00
13338865    56604         2 2014-04-09 07:06:00
13338865    56604         2 2014-04-09 07:06:00
```

I gave you just some data sets here. In fact every value read from the file is written eight times.

Comment: you are using in append mode. So if you run your script eight times, data will be replicated each time.

Comment: But I run it only one time. I even created a new script to ensure that the data is definitly read only once.

Comment: did u make sure that the database table is empty before running the script?

Comment: Yes, I delete everything from the table before starting the script.
I printed out the counter-df and everything is well there, so I assume the fault must happen somewhere when writing the data to the db

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a small sample of your data? And if so, can you post this?

Comment: I can reproduce it with every file I have (There are several thousands). Some of them in a different format. But the problem is the same.
You want to see the data from the db or from a df?

Comment: Both if possible, a small example (with just a couple of lines) of a dataframe, and the result you get in the db (or the result of `read_sql`)

Comment: I created a test file with only a single row, wrote it to the database and everything was fine. Then I tried a large file with 120 rows and the script added 8 rows for each value again.

Comment: Choose a file which gives the problem and fill in this information in the description of the problem. How many lines has the file? What is the number of rows of the dataframe "counter"? what is the number of row in the table of the database before and after the to_sql command?